# Flutter Android Notification Gets Automatically Dismissed From System Tray

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app that uses the Firebase firebase_messaging package. I can successfully send push notifications to the app when it is in the foreground, and onMessage gets triggered.

However, when the app is in the background, the push notification does not show up in the system tray. To debug, I turned on the Android notification history. Through the history, I can see that the notifications are being recorded in the system tray, but they never actually show up. It appears they are being automatically dismissed. Through the individual app settings, all notifications are allowed.

This app was working a few months back no problem, and push notifications would show in the system tray. But after updating some packages (including firebase_messaging) it no longer works. It also does not work with a physical device. Has anyone experienced an issue like this before?